# Increasing sql server varchar field size effect on application

Tags: sql-server, size, field

What is the effect of increasing the size of a varchar field from 50 to 60 on a sql server database taking into consideration that i am working on a legacy application working with .net framework 1.1 ?!

Comment: Perhaps you meant "legacy" instead of "legend" ?

Comment: It'll mean any string which is expected to be 50 chars long at most will now be 60 chars long... Without knowing your code's, it's rather difficult to assess how this will impact validation, etc.

Comment: At first: no impact at all. VARCHAR is always **variable** - e.g. it stores only as much data as is really needed. The impact it has on performance should be minimal under normal circumstances - whether or not your app will break if a string longer than 50 chars comes along, only you can decide that ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

50 to 60 is pretty trivial. If there's an index on the column you'll see slightly more pages in the index as you add larger sized data to the column since fewer values will fit on a single page. Other than that, I don't see much of an impact just referring to the size. You will have query and code that you'll have to take into account as well. You might also have a constraint that you have to be concerned with. That's about all I can think of.